# Importing emails with very long attachment file names using Redemption

Tags: outlook-redemption

I try to import MIME emails. I get them by saving the incoming stream from an email server to a file.
It works very well except when there are attachments with very long filenames.
The content of the file is handled perfectly fine but the name and filename are shown in Outlook 365 as "Untitled attachment".

I use RDOMail.Import(string Path, [object Type]) from Redemption v5.21.0.05378.

Can you please give me a hint how to keep the original filename?

This is a part of an email I try to import:

```
[...]
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; 
    name*0="this is an attachment with a really long file name - i
 hope "; name*1="it works like intended.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename*0="this is an attachment with a really long file name - i
 hope "; filename*1="it works as intended.txt"

This is the file content ...
[...]
```

Comment: That problem is fixed in the upcoming version 5.22 of Redemption. Please send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com, and I will send you an updated version. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!